# Can we use Max function inside Reduce function

Tags: equation-solving, functions, inequalities

I'm having a hard to find how to use the function max[.] and I'm almost sure the problem comes from this but I don't know what to do. I'm putting the code just below. Thanks in advance for any comment!

```
Reduce[{a^2/(
     4 (b + c1 + s θ1)) + β[(1 - p) a^2/(
        4 (b + c1 + s θ1)) + 
       p max[-F3 + a^2/(4 (b + c3 + s θ3)), a^2/(
         4 (b + c1 + s θ1)) ]] < q, a > 0, 1 > p > 0, s > 0, 
   1 > b > 0, 1 > θ1 > θ2 > θ3 > 0, c1 > 0, 
   c2 > 0, c3 > 0, F2 > 0, F3 > 0}, {c1, c2, c3, p, F2, F3, F3, 
   s}] /. q -> 
  a^2/(4 (b + c2 + s θ2)) - 
   F2 + β[(1 - p) a^2/(4 (b + c2 + s θ2)) + 
     p max[-F3 + a^2/(4 (b + c3 + s θ3)), a^2/(
       4 (b + c2 + s θ2)) ]]
```

Comment: You want `Max`, not `max`. Also you're using `β[...]`. If `β` is not a function and you intend to multiply it with the stuff in brackets then you should use  `β(...)`

Comment: Thanks for your comment! You're right however I'm still not being able to get a result from Mathematica applying those changes Mathematica keeps running. Should I wait or is there another way to proceed?

Comment: Yes it keeps running for me too. It might not have a nice solution.